# How to get input from cat over ssh in Perl

Tags: perl, input, ssh, pipe

I'm trying to cat a remote file over ssh and process it in local script line by line. So far I've tried this

```
open(INPUT,"| ssh user@host cat /dir1/dir2/file.dat")
```

but obviously it's only printing the file.dat to the STDOUT.

I know I can probably just scp the file and process it, but...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're piping *into* ssh. I think you want to move the pipe to the other end so you can read the output from that cat command.

Comment: yeaaaah, just found it myself by trial/error method :-D, but than you very much anyway

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
$file_contents = `ssh user@host cat /dir1/dir2/file.dat`;
@lines = split(/\n/, $file_contents);
.
.
. # process the file contents
```

That captures the output of the command (i.e. the contents of the file).

Comment: Why not just say `@lines = qx/ssh .../` (using qx here instead of backticks to avoid SO's tagging)?  This will run and split at the same time (though it'll preserve the \n's).  That said, this is less efficient. If the file is very large, you will have to load the whole thing into memory to deal with it.  If the connection is very slow, you will have to wait for the whole thing to load before processing any of it. The OP's solution, when fixed, suffers neither of these issues.  Backticks are generally to be avoided, in my experience.